# convert string to alphanumeric

Tags: string, go

I want to find if there is a better way to convert a given string to alpha numeric than to go by ascii value range as I am doing in the following code. It works as expected but wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Also my function buildAlphaN() converts string to lowercase to do the checks that follow.

if input: "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"
then output from buildAlphaN(): amanaplanacanalpanama

I have the whole solution for the problem for context, but my question is purely for the buildAlphaN() function.

```
// spaces part of palindrome? - ignored. 
import "strings"

//builds alphan and returns lower case
func buildAlphaN(s string) string {
    res := ""
    for _, v := range s {
         //0-9, A-Z, a-z
        if (v >= 48 && v <=57) || (v >= 65 && v <= 90) || (v >= 97 && v <= 122) {
            res += string(v)
        } 
    } 

    return strings.ToLower(res) 
}

func isPalindrome(s string) bool {
    if len(s) == 0 {
        //empty string
        return true
    } 

    s2 := buildAlphaN(s)
    fmt.Printf("s:%v s2:%v\n", s, s2)

    if palindromeCheck(s2) == true {
        return true
    }
    return false 
}

func  palindromeCheck(s string) bool {
    if len(s) == 1 {
        return true
    }

    for i, j := 0, len(s) - 1; i < j; i,j = i+1, j-1 {
        if s[i] == s[j] {
            continue
        } else {
            return false 
        } 
    }  
    return true
}
```

Comment: What is the reason you're converting to "alphanumeric"? This really matters for answering the question. For example, would Base64 do what you want?

Comment: "Cleaner" how? You're doing it in about 5 lines of fairly straightforward code, what problem do you have with the given code?

Comment: @Flimzy - given a string - want to find if it is a palindrome, considering only alphanumeric characters in the string.

Comment: @Adrian - theres no problem with the code, it works as expected. But I want to find if there is a more concise code / tricks to do the same. For example, I realized that I can do ( v >= '0' && v <='9') instead of ascii comparison (v >= 48 && v <=57) - which is far easier to do then remember ascii and compare...

Comment: Then try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - StackOverflow is for programming help, but it sounds like you already have a working solution.

Comment: The `unicode` package offers some functions that may be of interest to you (`IsDigit`, `IsLetter`...), but other than that, I don't see too many room for improvement here.

Comment: @EmilePels - ty - that is useful.

Comment: @Adrian - sure, will use codereview for such in future. But if I had asked how to write buildAlphaNumeric() would that have been a valid question here, without giving any implementation from my side. Only difference is that I have working code and seeking if thats how it should be done / is acceptable.

Comment: Asking how to write it would be too broad for SO. Asking generally if a working implementation could be somehow "better" is off-topic, and better suited to codereview. A question about how to fix a non-working implementation would be on-topic for SO, but that is not the situation you are in.

Comment: @Adrian: This question is on-topic. "if your question generally covers a software algorithm then you’re in the right place to ask your question!" See What topics can I ask about here? https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
)

func isPalindrome(s string) bool {
    rs := make([]rune, 0, len(s))
    for _, r := range s {
        if unicode.IsLetter(r) || unicode.IsNumber(r) {
            rs = append(rs, unicode.ToLower(r))
        }
    }

    for i, j := 0, len(rs)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        if rs[i] != rs[j] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func main() {
    s := "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"
    fmt.Println(isPalindrome(s))
}
```

Output:

```
true
```